# Fail to secure the SSL in tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

Our architecture is:

external users<---https--->web server(Apache HTTP server)<----->webapp server (tomcat)

We fail to pass the IBM AppScan, which is used to detect any security defects in webapp server, because it finds our tomcat server.xml file is not added the secure="yes" attribute in our port.

However the secure="yes" attribute should not be added to the tomcat server.xml file because we do not need a secure connection between web server and webapp server.

How can we fix the issue?
Are there any secure="yes" attribute can be added to the configuration file of web server(Apache HTTP server)?

Thanks & Regards,

Gordon

Comment: Ha ha ha, IBM's AppScan thinks that setting `secure="true"` makes the connector secure? That's quite funny. In fact, it often makes the connector *less* secure because it lies to the application and says "oh, yeah, sure... this is a secure connector *wink*, *wink*.

Comment: What protocol are you using to connect httpd to Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

If your users are accessing Tomcat (indirectly) through Apache httpd using TLS (https:// URL) then it is entirely appropriate to set `secure="true"` in your `<Connector>`. This tells your web application that the request being received is secure even when it is not (e.g. you are using plain-HTTP between httpd and Tomcat).

So, if you have set `scheme="https"` on your `<Connector>` then you probably want to also set `secure="true"`.

This is not a configuration change that you can make on the Apache httpd side... it must be done in Tomcat.